# Allow MEncoder to use more CPU

Tags: bash, mencoder

I am using MEncoder to combine a huge amount of jpg pictures into a time-lapse video. I have two main folders with about 10 subfolders each and in order to automate the process i am running:

```
find . -type d -name img -exec sh -c '(cd {} && /Volumes/SAMSUNG/PedestrianBehaviour/BreakableBonds/jpg2avi.sh t*)' ';'
```

where jpg2avi is the settings for MEncoder.

```
mencoder 'mf://t00*.jpg' -mf fps=10 -o raw.avi -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vhq:vbitrate=2000 -o out.avi
```

In order to parallelize it I have started this command in the two folders BreakableBonds and UnBreakableBonds. However each process only uses about 27% so a total of a bit above 50%. Are there any way that I can accelerate this? such that each process takes up about 50%. (I am aware that 50% on each process is not possible.)

Comment: Without incorporating `jpg2avi.sh` (aside: using a `.sh` extension for executable scripts is not a good practice; see https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful.shtml for discussion), this question is rather incomplete.

Comment: I have now updated it with the jpg2avi.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the video codec you're using (x264 is a good choice), one encode should be able to saturate several CPU cores.  I usually use ffmpeg directly, because mencoder was designed with some AVI-like assumptions.

See [ffmpeg's wiki page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) on how to do this.

Again, I'd highly recommend h.264 in an mkv or mp4 container, rather than anything in an avi container.  h.264 in avi is a hack, and the usual codec for avi is divx (h.263).  h.264 is a big step forward.

h.264 is for video what mp3 is for audio: the first codec that's Good Enough, and that came along just as CPUs were getting fast enough to do it in realtime, and disks and networks were capable of handling the file sizes that produce good quality.  Use it with [ffmpeg as a frontend for libx264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

h.265 (and vp9) are both better codecs (in terms of compression efficiency) than h.264, but are far less widely supported, and take more CPU time.  If you want to use them, use ffmpeg as a frontend for libx265 or libvpx.  x265 is under heavy development, so it's probably improved, but several months ago, given equal encode CPU time, x265 didn't beat x264 in quality per bitrate.  Given *much* more CPU time, x265 can do a great job and make as-good-looking encodes at much less bitrate than x264, though.

All 3 of those codecs are multi-threaded and can saturate 4 cores even at fast settings.  At higher settings (spending more CPU time per block), you can saturate at least 16 cores, I'd guess.  I'm not sure, but I think you can efficiently take advantage of 64 cores, and maybe more, on a HD x265 encode.

At fast settings and high bitrates, the gzip-style entropy coding final stage (i.e. CABAC for x264) limits the amount of CPUs you can keep busy.  It's a serial task, so the whole encode only goes as fast as one CPU can compress the final bitstream.